# How do you configure IntelliJ to use the Java, Scala, and SBT that were installed by Homebrew?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ CE 2017.2 on a Mac running Sierra. I've installed Java, Scala, and SBT using Homebrew and I'd like to have the same environment I have in the shell running in IntelliJ. How do I configure IntelliJ to use the existing tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## For SBT:

`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | SBT`

On the `Laucher` section select `custom` and point to where homebrew installed sbt.

## For Scala

`Project Structure | Global Libraries | + | Scala SDK`

On the window that poped up click `Browse` and point to where brew installed scala.

## For Java

`Project Structure | SDKs | + | JDK`

On the pop up window choose the location of the jdk installed by homebrew.

### Edit for SBT caveats

The sbt version is controlled by the setting `sbt.version` in the file `project/build.properties`, if that version is set to an SBT version other than the one in homebrew, intellij will download it and use it.

Make sure `sbt.version` as the same version number as the sbt installed by homebrew

The same may happen for scala, but in this case you can configure multiple SDKs.

Comment: I set the SBT launcher path to where homebrew installed sbt 1.0 (`/usr/local/bin/sbt`), but when I create a new project the versions dropdown shows various 0.13.X versions. Why isn't IntelliJ recognizing the sbt I configured?

Comment: thanks! Is there a template that Intellij uses to generate `project/build.properties` that I can edit so that it's correct when I create the project?

Comment: I do not know that part. I usually like to confirm the version myself as that file is not specific to intellij but to sbt.

Comment: I had to point IntelliJ specifically to the sbt-launch.jar, in my case (sbt 1.4.6 installed via brew) it was /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.4.6/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar